# Should POINT_SPRITES or TRIANGLES be used for big quads

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am on a pickle right now, I have a particle system that has about 500 particles without rotation and the size of each particle can be as big as 100 pixels, I made tests with 2 different ways of drawing them,first by using point sprites and the second by using 4 vertices and 6 indices to make a quad,I tested both but I get almost the same performance on my machine. 
I have read that for big point sprites in some GPUs are actually coverted to triangles and this is slow, so its better to draw them as triangles from the beginning but shouldn't this mean that you have more data to push to the GPU?

Floats used for each point:

- Point sprites:**4**(x,y,size,color)
- Triangle quads:(16(x,y,color,textureCoords)*4)+6(indice)=**22**

So the question is should I care to put an option in the settings menu from where the user can switch between these 2 in case his gpu is better at drawing directly triangles or point sprites?

Comment: All the particles are drawn with one draw call? If no, that would be the first thing to try to change. If yes, chances are your bottleneck is either fill rate or pixel shader (it's often the case with mobile hw). If you want to test the rasterization performance, you should try setting a very small viewport (like 1px) to bypass the aforementioned bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically point sprites should be faster but have some disadvantages.

Your particles can be quite big and point sprites are clipped at their center coordinate.

The best options would be using instanced rendering but it's not available in OpenGL ES 2.

There is an excellent answer about point sprites and particle systems - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400234/1351828